# showing number of clicks within 10 seconds using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to develop this game that requires a user to rapidly click a button my seconds are set to 10, that the timer only starts when you click the button, there's a show me button that just shows the result, and after 10 seconds the total should popup.

my problem is that I can't seem to get the increments right, and the clicks still register after the timer is done which it shouldn't do. I need help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#total').hide();
    var sec = 10;
    $('.setthis').click(function() {
        var timer = setInterval(function() {
            sec = sec - 1;
            if (sec > 0) {
                $('#target').click(function() {
                    $('#total').html(function(i, val) {
                        return val * 1 + 1
                    });
                })
            }
            if (sec == 0) {
                $('#total').show();
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 1000);
    })
    $('#showme').click(function() {
        $('#total').show();
    })
});
```

Comment: You're binding `$('#target')` click handler multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you click button, you are setting the interval which is not right. You should rather set the interval once (on first click) and then use it to mark end of 10 seconds.

Try the following:

```
$('#total').hide();
var clicks = 0;
var timerSet = false;
var timerDone = false;
$('#setthis').click(function () {
    if (!timerSet) {
        timerSet = true;
        setInterval(function () {
            timerDone = true;
        }, 10000);
    }
    if (!timerDone) {
        clicks++;
        $('#total').text(clicks);
    }

});
$('#showme').click(function () {
    $('#total').show();
});
```

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9PFNU/)

Comment: thank you so much this was wracking my brain for the longest time. I'll remember this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your complete game I made with JavaScript

```
<div id="displayTime"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0;var counterTicks=0;
var timer1 = setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
function myTimer()
{
counterTicks++;
document.getElementById("displayTime").innerHTML="Timer:"+counterTicks;
if(counterTicks>=10){
window.clearInterval(timer1);
alert("Your total Clicks - "+clicks);
}
}
</script> 


<input value="Click" type="button" onclick="clicks++;">
```

You are achieving this with simple JavaScript :)